# Content of expression fields in forms is sometimes not displayed

Tags: ms-access

We have a ACCDB including a lot of forms with expression fields (e.g. "=[FieldA] + [FieldB]"). The ms access db is executed with the access runtime (2019) on a Win10 terminal server. All Forms have been migrated from access 2002 to access 2019 (per OASIS SVN Export/Import).

Mostly the content of expression fields would be displayed as expected, but in individual cases all/some expression fields in the form are empty (also after waiting some time). The content of the other fields is displayed. This beviour is data independend and the field expressions are correct. Mostly ist works, but somtimes not (for the same expression field, data record and form). But if a expression field gets the focus, the content is displayed.

Perhaps it depends on the workload of the pc the access db is running. But i'm not an ms access expert. Another problem is, that an mistakenly empty field could be misinterpred by the user.

One solution is to use the onCurrent event of the form to set the field content explicitly (doesn't work for endless forms) or outsource the calculation in the db view.

I am searching for a general solution, without having to modify all forms (> 150). I can't image this is a general problem with ms access.

Many thanks for any help

Comment: This is not the general behaviour, so - most likely - something else is going on. Double-check the doings of the form(s).

Comment: Issue occurs on all machines that run db? Does this occur in accdb or accde?  Try decompile and recompile db. Try importing everything to a new db file.

Comment: Thanks, I will investigate further. Some of the forms showing the problem are very simple and I didn't find anything unusual until now. I also compared the strange behavior with some users. We opened the same form with the same data record and became different results regarding the empty expression fields. We have a similar problem with conditional formatting of fields in endelss forms. Mostly it works fine, sometimes the color is render asynchrounosly with long delay and in rare cases it isn't rendered. Maybe someting with the workload of the user pc or an hidden internal error.

Comment: The db is an accdb and is executed on a win10 terminal server. Each user has it's own db instance. The issue occurs only sometimes by different users. For deployment we build a new ms access db per jenkins with oasis svn (all ms access objects are imported). If the issue occurs next time, I will try to decompile/recompile the db explicitly on the terminal server and look if the problem further occurs. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Cause of the problem were some java processes started in vba per WScript.Shell and WaitOnReturn option. The problem occurs only if one of the processe was running. As a solution we now avoid the WaitOnReturn option if possible.